# How to navigate to the same page with a new instance created on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How could I navigate from SomePage to another SomePage with a new instance created?
Here is my code in ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommandEx<SomeItemSchema> ItemClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (itemClickCommand == null)
            {
                itemClickCommand = new RelayCommandEx<SomeItemSchema>(
                    (item) =>
                    {
                        NavigationServices.NavigateToPage("SomePage", item);
                    });
            }
            return itemClickCommand;
        }
    }`
```

Code in CodeBehind of SomePage: `this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;`

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        _navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        SomeItemSchema parameter = e.Parameter as SomeItemSchema;
        SomeItemModel.SelectItem(parameter);
        await SomeItemModel.LoadItemsAsync(parameter.Url);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to navigate to a new instance of the same page then just navigate to the same page but give it a different timestamp.

Like so

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SomePage.xaml?" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
```

Now each SomePage will push to the nagivation stack.